# For $x \geq 2$, prove the inequality $(x+1) cos \frac{ \pi}{x+1}-x cos \frac{\pi}{x}>1$

Tags: inequality

> For $x \geq 2$, prove the inequality $(x+1) cos \frac{ \pi}{x+1}-x cos \frac{\pi}{x}>1$.

I am not sure where to begin. A hint is helpful.

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg ok let me think about this

Comment: Maybe the following can help? https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h375639p2073103

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg ahh i see the exact problem posted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean value theorem

$$g(a) - g(b)= g'(\xi)(a - b)$$ where $\xi\in\left[a,b\right]$.

In your case the function $g(x)=x\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)$

Put $a=x+1, b=x$, and get the bound on the derivative.

The derivative is
$$g'(\xi)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{\xi}\right)+\left(\frac{\pi}{\xi}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{\xi}\right)$$

We have to show that $g'(\xi)\gt 1$ for $\xi \in [2,\infty)$.

**Claim:** $g'(\xi)$ is a monotonically decreasing function. To show this, we have to show that $g''(\xi)$ is always negative for $\xi \in [2,\infty)$.

$$g''(\xi)=-\frac{\pi}{\xi^{3}}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{\xi}\right)$$

$g''(\xi)\leq 0$ for $\xi \in [2,\infty)$, where equality holds only at $\xi=2$. This implies that $g'(\xi)$ is a decreasing function in $\xi \in [2,\infty)$.

Also observe that
$$g'(2)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ and $$\\\lim_{\xi\to\infty}g'(\xi)\to 1$$

The function $g'(\xi)$ decreases monotonically from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ at $\xi=2$ and approaches 1 as $\xi$ approaches $\infty$.  In other words,
 $g'(\xi)\gt 1$ for $\xi \in [2,\infty)$.

Comment: It's exactly, which does not help, I think. Can you explain please your reasoning. Why do you think that it helps? Thank you!

Comment: Well, spruce asked about where to begin. I just wrote exactly that. And I left at the part where inequality has to be proved.

Comment: Show please, how do you end the proof by your hint?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for asking.